# Javascript loop stop using if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

```
$("div").each(function(i, obj) {
  i++;
  var stopLoop = false; 
  if (!$(obj).attr('style') && stopLoop !== true) {
    $(obj).attr('style', 'background:'+getRandomColor()+';');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Above method work, it will add one new color to my `div` whenever the function got fired. But because of the return false is used, my code after it will not run. So I try to use if condition instead of return false, it doesn't work the same.

```
// doesn't work

    $("div").each(function(i, obj) {
      i++;
      var stopLoop = false; 
      if (!$(obj).attr('style') && stopLoop !== true) {
        $(obj).attr('style', 'background:'+getRandomColor()+';');
        stopLoop = true;
      }
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `return true`? `return true` is the same as **continue** while `return false` is the same as **break**.

Comment: have you tried using `return` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the solution below

```
var stopLoop = false;

$("div").each(function(i, obj) {
  if(i === 0) {
    stopLoop = false;
  }

  i++;

  if (!$(obj).attr('style') && !stopLoop) {
    $(obj).attr('style', 'background:'+getRandomColor()+';');
    stopLoop = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: if you have stopLoop out there in the outer scope of each function, why would you want to do the check for `i === false again`?

Comment: @Jennifer I don't see your whole app just the fragment that you provided. If you use it multiple times e.g. in a function or an event handler the variable `stopLoop` should be reset to `false` else the second condition will be always false after the first loop execution.

Answer (score 0):

Try with break :

```
$("div").each(function(i, obj) {
    i++;
    if (!$(obj).attr('style')) {
        $(obj).attr('style', 'background:'+getRandomColor()+';');
        break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

declare stopLoop variable in global scope.
in you case stopLoop is deaclared inside function and after function ends it's work variable will be deleted. and on the other iteration it will be declared again with value false